# Passing parameter with a pipe in it into a powershell script - how do I escape the pipe?

Tags: powershell

Escaping chars in powershell is just silly. I've tried everything I can find to try and escape this pipe in a parameter that I'm passing into a powershell script, but I absolutely cannot escape it. It's nuts. I make sure to pass the param in single quotes, and have tried all of the powershell/windows escape chars (`,``,\,\,^,^^). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example of test script:

```
$cmd = $Args[0] #set first parameter received to $cmd to run with Invoke-Expression (must wrap param in single quotes if it contains spaces)  
write-host $cmd
```

Calling test script with a pipe containing command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell -executionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat none "D:\test_powershell\app\test_wrapper.ps1" 'test1 | test2'
```

Results:

```
'test2'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few notes:

1. You don't need `cmd`. Just call PowerShell directly.
2. `-InputFormat` can be either Text or XML. `None` is not a valid value here.
3. Use the following (which is mentioned in the help too if escaping issues arise):

   ```
   powershell "&{ &'D:\test_powershell\app\test_wrapper.ps1' 'test 1 | test2' }"
   ```

Comment: This works. I'm able to escape every special char I throw at it now. The -InputFormat none is actually important in my case. If I don't include this, my powershell session hangs and waits for more input. I had read that -InputFormat none is valid when used in the manner I'm using it in (the cmd is also necessary since I'm running these commands through a php page). Thanks again, this rocks.

Answer (score 4):

from cmd the escape character for the pipe would be the carat ^